Android で ForegroundService への MVVM パターン適用と Usecase の使用方法 (Activity や Fragment を使用しない場合の MVVM 適用方法)
Android でバックグラウンドサービスを使用するアプリを作っています。
どのようなものかといいますと、現在端末上で使用中のアプリを取得し、それをユーザーが保存しているアプリデータと照合し、使用している時間などに応じてフローティングView や通知を表示する、というものです。（全てはお教えできないので簡単な説明です）
問題は、Serviceクラスの内容がとてつもない量になってしまうということです...
そこで MVVM を適用することを考えました。
その場合...
・XXService

xxServiceViewModel

aaUsecase (レポジトリアクセス)
bbUsecase (APIアクセス)



のようになるのかと思いましたが、View にあたるものがありません...
通常ですと、
Activity → Fragment(View) → ViewModel → Usecase → レポジトリやAPI(Model)
のような形になるという風に理解しています。
今回の場合 Activity や Fragment を使用していないので、View は省略してもいいのでしょうか？
ただ、そうすると Service クラスにFloatingView のインスタンスや表示処理を置かないといけないのでコード量が多いままになってしまいます...
できれば Service クラスにはサービス自体の状態や起動、終了に関することのみを書き、FloatingView などの表示処理は切り分けたいと考えています。
何かいいお考えをお持ちの方はいらっしゃいませんか？
(また、上記の理解で間違っているところがありましたらぜひご指摘お願いいたします。)
